# Android canvas Pinch to Zoom with pivot point

Tags: android, zooming, pinchzoom

I'm trying to implement Pinch to Zoom to position. I'm working on it over a week now and I can't figure it out.

**Here is my problem:**

I created a custom view, extending `SurfaceView`and implementing `ScalingGestureDetector`. Everything works fine, while I haven't scaled my canvas yet or pivot point are the same as in the previous scaling. When pivot point is different than in the previous scaling, canvas jumps to different x,y position and scaling to it not to finger focus point. I can't use matrix, because I draw text and rects, not bitmap.

**Here's my code**

```
public class CustomSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float focusX, focusY;
    private float scale = 1f;

    private void init(Context context) {
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        // other init code
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        tryDrawing(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int frmt, int w, int h) {
        tryDrawing(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}

    public void tryDrawing() {
        tryDrawing(getHolder());
    }

    private void drawMyStuff(final Canvas canvas) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Drawing...");

        for(Pixel pixel : pixels) {
            drawRect(canvas, pixel);
        }
    }

    public void tryDrawing(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to draw...");

        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot draw onto the canvas as it's null");
        } else {
            canvas.scale(scale, scale, focusX , focusY);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            drawMyStuff(canvas);

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        scale = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));

        tryDrawing();
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        focusX = detector.getFocusX();
        focusY = detector.getFocusY();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    }
}`
```

If someone don't understand exactly what I mean, I can create some video later.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? I really need some help...

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like yours in one of my projects. I tried to think out of the box and instead of trying to give a pivot for the scale.
I used the default pivot (top-left corner..) but I translated the canvas to the pivot, so the top left corner will be at the position of your pivot. After that I translated my bitmaps and rects back to their proper place. Something like this might do it:

```
private void drawMyStuff(final Canvas canvas) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Drawing...");

    for(Pixel pixel : pixels) {
        drawRect(canvas, pixel); // translate your rect with x : -focusX, y: -focusY
    }
}

public void tryDrawing(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Trying to draw...");

    Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
    if (canvas == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot draw onto the canvas as it's null");
    } else {
        // Translate the canvas (so the top left corner will be in the wanted position and you can use it as a pivot)
        canvas.translate(focusX , focusY);
        canvas.scale(scale, scale); // Use the default 0,0 pivot
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        drawMyStuff(canvas);

        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps..